# Replace with Regex in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file which consists of places where there are multiple underscores. I need to convert them all to single underscores.

How can I do this in Node?

My current solution:

```
var fs = require("fs");
filename = "questions.txt";
ofilename = "o.txt";
fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/_+/g, "_");

  fs.writeFile(ofilename, result, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

This gives me a file where everything is in binary.

Comment: You can do this without JS, using `sed` in terminal `sed 's/__*/_/g' questions.txt`

Comment: the data remains the same

Comment: add `> o.txt` to save to a file `sed 's/__*/_/g' test.txt > o.txt`

Comment: or `-i` to modify file `sed -i 's/__*/_/g' test.txt`

Comment: @JacekRojek sorry it might have been an encoding issue. this gave me the same result on utf16. but on changing to utf8 everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well.

```
var fs = require("fs");
filename = "./questions.txt";
ofilename = "o.txt";
fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
  var result = data.replace(/_+/g, "_");

  fs.writeFile(ofilename, result, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

- produces:

```
toto

_
_
rr
```

- from:

```
toto

__
__
rr
```

Be sure that your input file is well utf8 encoded.

Comment: https://ibb.co/yNcyP53
the output is this, when I run it

Comment: I am not sure if my input file is utf8. It is just a txt file.
What other formats can I use?

Comment: and show your input file encoding (at bottom right of the ide)

Comment: it says utf16le

Comment: So click on it, select "save with encoding" and select "utf8", assuming you are on vscode